# Angular Ag-grid side "Columns Tool Panel" get checkbox event

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

Is there any way to get the check/uncheck/change event of side panel columns?

document I have followed https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/tool-panel-columns/. but found none.

**Enterprise version**

[image]

Comment: Did you find any solution for the select/unselect event?

Answer (score 1):

I found something that can interest you.
I used onVisibleColumn event

```
function handleColumnVisible(event: ColumnVisibleEvent) {
    /* verify onVisibleColumn has not been triggered by something else that tool panel clic */ 
    if (event.source !== 'toolPanelUi') {
      return;
    }
    // verify event has a column
    if (null !== event.column) {
      const colId = event.column?.colId;
      // use visible to check if your column is checked or not (visible means checked)
      if (event.column.visible) {
        // ... your code
      }
    }
}

 <AgGridReact
          ref={gridRef}
          rowData={rowData}
          columnDefs={columnDefs}
          onColumnVisible={handleColumnVisible}
/>
```